# Not working on cancellation of POST in Axios

Tags: javascript, post, axios

The code is not working after the cancellation of POST in Axios. Can you tell me, what is wrong?

```js
      var CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
      var source = CancelToken.source();

      axios
        .post(
          "http://api.image-service/upload",
          data,
          {
            headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
          },
          {
            cancelToken: source.token
          }
        )

        .then(response => {
          if (response.data.StatusCode == 1) {
            console.log("Retry", response.data);
          } else if (response.data.StatusCode == 0) {
            console.log("Success", response.data);
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          if (axios.isCancel(error)) {
            console.log("Post Request canceled");
          } else {
            console.log("Error connecting to server", error);
          }
        });

      source.cancel();
```

And one more question: can I do cancellation from other function? For example: if I wait more then 1 minute, I want to click the button for cancel request.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Please edit your question by providing more relevant details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue with a get request.
You need to pass headers in axios properties.
`axios.get(url, { cancelToken: ..., headers: { ... } }).then...`